# DateFormat.MEDIUM cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use this line of code, but I'm get an error for "MEDIUM" that says that it cannot be resolved or is not a field. I imported import java.util.Date also. Can anyone tell me why this piece of code isn't working?

```
 Date today = new Date();
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you imported `java.text.DateFormat` also

Comment: I have import android.text.format.DateFormat; as well. I changed it to java.text.DateFormat and it worked. Thanks!